# Delete several sequential file names, but ignore part of the first

Tags: shell, files, wildcards, rm

Sometimes, my scripts get trapped in infinite loops. When the loop creates new files, things get messy.

I currently have this file name format:

```
Task.4883.store.log
```

where `4883` is a counter.

I need to delete all files, except the first 10 (i.e. counter in 0-9, inclusive). Currently, around 10k files are created before I can react and stop the script. SSD's are really fast.

It gets a bit harder by `rm` not accepting that many arguments:
`-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long`

Oh, and I'm currently on a mac.

Comment: none of the answers addressed the point about the first ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name 'Task.??*.store.log' | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Is the `-f` necessary - or even a good idea?

Comment: It depends. If the files are read-only (unlikely) then yes (-f), but I agree that in this case it is probably not needed. However, in a non-interactive script I always use `-f` to avoid potential prompts.

Comment: A person copy/pasting the answer might not know where to put the -f flag, or that they need to add it, if the script does not work.

Answer (score 5):

A POSIX one, can handle file which contain newline in filename:

```
find . -name 'Task.??*.store.log' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
rm Task.<10->.store.log
```

To avoid the *arguments list too long*:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc 
zargs Task.<10->.store.log -- rm
```